# After press of the button no sound plays in the iOS simulator

Tags: swift

I'm looking for reasons why my sound won't play in the iOS simulator.

Program runs but when I press the button no sound plays.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var player:AVAudioPlayer?
func playSound() {
    if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sound",       withExtension: "mp3") {
    do {
    try      AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
    if let thePlayer = player {
    thePlayer.prepareToPlay()
     thePlayer.play()
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from             a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
        playSound()
    }
}
```

Do I need changes in my code or in my simulator setup?

Comment: The quality filters on our site are there for a reason. Don't try to circumvent them by adding noise. Just step back, re-read the [help] and [edit] to imrpove.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, you have to go to System Preferences > Sound > Sound Effects and then uncheck and recheck "Play user interface sound effects".

Answer (score 0):

Actually found out that all I had to do was delete the file and re add it. Instead of dragging the file into Xcode I needed to add it by right clicking and adding the file that way